# How to count total unique user doing transaction each month

Tags: sql, duckdb

Hi there is a `order_table`, the table contains the following fields
order_id, user_id, item_id, gmv, order_time.

I already write to find the month from transactions

```
%%sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT bulan AS bulan_transaksi
FROM (
  SELECT
    DATE_PART('month', order_time) AS bulan
  FROM
    order_table
  )
GROUP BY
  bulan;
```

and the results are just

```
    bulan_transaksi
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Try `SELECT bulan, count(*) FROM ...`.

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found it!
here is the answer,

```
%%sql
select count(user_id) as jumlah_pengguna, DATE_PART('month', order_time) as bulan from order_table group by bulan
```

The results is

```
    jumlah_pengguna bulan
0   6165            1
1   5573            2
2   6069            3
3   5966            4
4   6062            5
5   206             6
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you came up with does not count the *unique* users by month. I think what you want is

```sql
select 
  count(distinct user_id) as jumlah_pengguna, 
  DATE_PART('month', order_time) as bulan 
from order_table 
group by bulan
```